# Sinatra Errno::ENOENT - cannot find file

Tags: ruby, sinatra

While trying to run this app with sinatra it throws an error, saying it cannot find a json file.  When I test the methods outside sinatra, they work fine.
The file database.json is located in the same folder as app.rb.  When I don't execute the method "read", sinatra works well.

This is app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

class Articles
attr_reader :read

def read
  JSON.parse(File.read('database.json'))
end

def create
  "Here I am!"
end

def update(title, content)
  added_art = {"title": title, "content": content}
  json = File.read('database.json')
  secondJsonArray = JSON.parse(json)
  secondJsonArray << added_ar
  File.open("database.json","w") do |f|
  f.puts JSON.pretty_generate(secondJsonArray)
  end

end

end


get '/' do
  @all = Articles.new.read
erb :index
end

post '/' do
  @title = params[:title]
  @content = params[:content]
  Articles.new.update(@title, @content)
  redirect 'http://localhost:4567/'
end
```

The error message I get is the following:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - database.json
JSON.parse(File.read('database.json'))
```

HOWEVER, when I execute the individual app.rb file from Sublime Text, it does work and I can get the url just fine.

Extra

Comment: Are you aware that you can just use `redirect '/'` which works then also for different hosts and ports

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a wrong path since you start it from a different context try to use a path like this:

```
def read
  path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/database.json")
  JSON.parse(File.read(path))
end
```